# What would the snippet(s) look like for multiple google analytics tracking IDs?

Tags: google-analytics

I'd like to include 3 tracking IDs on all pages. I'm using the Google Analytics module and there are three fields in the custom javascript code under advanced settings.

Comment: What do Google's docs say they should look like? I doubt there would be a Drupal-specific answer to this question

Comment: Google API question, nothing todo with Drupal.

Comment: I see from the Google API that I should add this before: ga('create', 'UA-12345-6', 'auto', {'name': 'newTracker'}); and this after: ga('newTracker.send', 'pageview');. I'm not seeing this work when I put those snippets in the before and after fields in the GA module. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#multipletrackers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Universal Google Analytics, in the Google Analytics Module 7.x-2.0 @ /admin/config/system/googleanalytics > ADVANCED SETTINGS > CUSTOM JAVASCRIPT CODE > Code snippet (after)

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-Y', 'auto', {'name': 'foo'});
ga(function(foo) {
  foo.send('pageview');
});
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-Y', 'auto', {'name': 'bar'});
ga(function(bar) {
  bar.send('pageview');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want more than one person to have access to the google analytics property, the easiest way would eb to invite them to the property (within analytics you can add new users).

If you really need more than one trackingcode within the site add in the field *Code snippet (before)*:

```
ga('create', 'UA-12345-6', 'auto', {'name': 'newTracker'});
```

and in the field *Code snippet (after)*:

```
ga('newTracker.send', 'pageview');
```

But again, that only makes sense, when you restict each property to certain portion of the site.